# How to import a js file from VSCode extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an old VSCode extension project that developed two years ago and I haven't touch it since then. Today I want to add a new feature to it so I opened it up and made the modification. Basically I modified the file parser.js, which was generated by peggyjs. When I try to invoke the extension's feature, I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './parser'
Require stack:
- c:\projects\myextension\out\extension.js
- c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
- c:\vscode\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\vscode\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
    at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:987:15)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:832:27
    at Function.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.<anonymous> (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:118:14563)
    at Function.<anonymous> (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:113:64900)
    at Function._load (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:113:64268)
    at Module.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:19)
    at Module.require (c:\Users\eyang\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.84.51\dist\extension.js:8:366165)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\projects\myextension\src\extension.ts:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:32)
    at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:876:12
    at Function.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Function.<anonymous> (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:118:14563)
    at Function.<anonymous> (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:113:64900)
    at Function._load (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:113:64268)
    at Module.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:19)
    at Module.require (c:\Users\eyang\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.84.51\dist\extension.js:8:366165)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Function.r [as __$__nodeRequire] (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:5:101)
    at h._loadCommonJSModule (c:\vscode\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:113:66459)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

I haven't changed any line in extention.ts. Why the import of "parser.js" failed? The import part looks like this:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
const parser = require('./parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
```

This is the directory tree structure:

```
PS C:\projects\myextension> tree -I node_modules
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── images
│   └── icon.png
├── out
│   ├── extension.js
│   ├── extension.js.map
│   └── test
│       ├── runTest.js
│       ├── runTest.js.map
│       └── suite
│           ├── extension.test.js
│           ├── extension.test.js.map
│           ├── index.js
│           └── index.js.map
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── snippets
│   └── [Ultimate snippet template].code-snippets
├── src
│   ├── extension.ts
│   ├── parser.js
│   ├── peggy.txt
│   └── test
│       ├── runTest.ts
│       └── suite
│           ├── extension.test.ts
│           └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── vsc-extension-quickstart.md

8 directories, 22 files
PS C:\projects\myextension>
```

The `parser.js` file is generated by peggyjs and is very long. But it basically looks like this:

```
module.exports = // Generated by Peggy 3.0.2.
    //
    // https://peggyjs.org/
    (function () {
        "use strict";

        function peg$subclass(child, parent) {
            function C() { this.constructor = child; }
            C.prototype = parent.prototype;
            child.prototype = new C();
        }

        function peg$SyntaxError(message, expected, found, location) {
            var self = Error.call(this, message);
            // istanbul ignore next Check is a necessary evil to support older environments
            if (Object.setPrototypeOf) {
                Object.setPrototypeOf(self, peg$SyntaxError.prototype);
            }
            self.expected = expected;
            self.found = found;
            self.location = location;
            self.name = "SyntaxError";
            return self;
        }


        ...

        return {
            SyntaxError: peg$SyntaxError,
            parse: peg$parse
        };
    })()
    ;
```